# How to replace fread() from file, with command line argument?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
uint8_t in[BLOCK256], out[32];
bytesread = fread( in, 1, BLOCK256, fp );
```

then the `in` variable is passed to another function.

I was trying to substitute the reading from file functionality 
with inserting a string as an argument to the program using `strcpy(in,argv[1])`.

The result I am getting though its different in those two cases. I am not sure what the problem is.

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    #define BLOCK256 64
    FILE *fp;
    int i, j, bytesread;
    uint8_t in[BLOCK256], out[32];
    state256 S;
    blake256_test();

    for( i = 1; i < argc; ++i )
    {
        fp = fopen( *( argv + i ), "r" );
        if ( fp == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Error: unable to open %s\n", *( argv + i ) );
            return 1;
        }

        blake256_init( &S );

        while( 1 )
        {
            bytesread = fread( in, 1, BLOCK256, fp );
            if ( bytesread )
               blake256_update( &S, in, bytesread );
            else
               break;
        }

        blake256_final( &S, out );

        for( j = 0; j < 32; ++j )
           printf( "%02x", out[j] );

        fclose( fp );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of reading the contents of a file I want to pass a string as a command line argument.

Comment: `strcpy(argv[1])` is wrong format....

Comment: @SouravGhosh can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Do you want to read the input from the command line argument `argv` or from an existing file ?

Comment: In which way does the result differ? What is the content of the file, what do you pass as parameters?

Comment: @AxelIsouard as a command line argument

Comment: @Aconcagua in the file I write a "hello" string and then in the modified I want to pass the same string as a command line argument

Comment: @orestiss I think we need to know the origin of `fp` and `BLOCK256`, I feel confused about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Could it be that your file actually contains a newline after "hello"? It will be contained in the data read into `in`, but you won't get one from the command line - depending on what blake256_update actually does, this might give you different results.

Comment: By the way, you do not have to copy argv[1] into in, you can pass it directly to blake256_final with a cast, together with strlen(argv[1]).

Comment: int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
 char test[128];

 if (argc > 1)
 {
  strcpy(test, argv[1]);

  printf(test);

  printf("\n");
 }

 return 0;
}

Comment: Do `echo -n "hello" > testfile` to prevent the newline (if you're on Linux)

Comment: Oh, another possible error: `blake256_update(&S, in, bytesread);` when you passed argv[1] (copied or not) as second argument argument - have you thought of passing `strlen(argv[1])` as third one?

Comment: @Henno Brasdsma using the `echo -n "hello" > testfile` worked ( I mean I got the same result). Not sure why. I didn't add manually a new line...

Comment: @orestiss `od -c filename` shows you the full contents of filename. Editors (like vi) tend to add newline characters in the final line.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(argc, argv[]){
     state256 S;
     blake_test();
     unsigned char digest[32];
     for (i=1; i < argc; i++){
          blake256_init(&S);
          blake256_update(&S,argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
          blake256_final(&S, digest);
          print_digest(digest); /* your print loop as function, with extra newline */
     }
     return 0;
}
```

will do the trick (hash every commandline argument string). Write the print function and add `string.h` headerfiles etc.
BTW you are not reading from stdin in either case.